# android countdown to milliseconds

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, date-formatting

i am trying to make a countdown application, where the maximum time will be under 10 mins, and i would like to have it show as mm:ss:ms (not too sure if ms is the term for milliseconds). and this is what i have here

```
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.counterView);
    new CountDownTimer(16069000, 10) { // adjust the milli seconds here
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                    ));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

is it currently showing hh:mm:ss, i tried to play around with it, but couldn't get it working. I tried to put the format as

> "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d"

but i got lost when i was trying to add the milliseconds part inside the setText.

Answer (score 2):

You're explicitly displaying Hours:Minutes:Seconds here:

```
        text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                ));
```

change it to something like:

```
        long m = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
        long s = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished - m*60*1000);
        long ms = millisUntilFinished - m*60*1000 - s*1000; 
        text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",m,s,ms));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is code

```
 CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(150000, 1000);  // set time here
  timer.start();

define class here

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // timeTextView.setText("Completed.");

            this.cancel();

            finish();
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            caaryLong = millis;
            String hms = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                    .toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);

            timeTextView.setText(hms);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using android studio than there is one external library

**Step 1:In build.gradle(Module App)**

compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'

**Step 2:In your activity .xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.countdowntimer.MainActivity">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_milliseconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MilliSeconds"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3: Initialize Textview and Chronometer**

```
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private long startTime = 1000;
    private final long interval = 100;
```

**Step 4:In OnChronometerTickListener**

```
chronometer.start();
chronometer.setBase(1);
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                setDateTime();
            }
        });
```

**step 5 : Create function**

```
public void setDateTime() {
        countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        countDownTimer.start();  

} 

 public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tvMilliseconds.setText("" + millisUntilFinished);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to get it done with the following code `text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                        ));`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by getting lost?

If you were asking what value to put for the millisecond part, just use

```
millisUntilFinished % 1000
```